# How to use tapply in a loop in R

Tags: r, tapply

This might look like a simple question, and it probably is.

I have a dataset with 43 species and 24 environmental variables, for which  I would like to calculate the mean value +/- CI 95% for each environmental variables for each species.

I figured out how to calculate the mean +/- CI 95% for one species and one environmental variable. But how to form a data frame (43 x 24) with all the values... I don't want to do it one by one...

```
ci.mean(tapply(allbryo$prep_anne, allbryo$Myl_ano , mean))
```

I suppose it's pretty simple, but I am new in R. Thank you!

Comment: Check out the [split-apply-combine](http://stat545.com/block024_group-nest-split-map.html) functionalities behind `dplyr`, this should fairly directly address the issue  you face

Comment: Please share sample of your data so others can help. See more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1

Comment: @Tung, here is an example of my data.                                                       data = matrix(1:12, ncol = 4)
colnames(data)=c("spe1", "spe2","env1","env2")
data=data.frame(data)
mean(tapply(data$env1, data$spe1 , mean))                                                 As you can see, I am able to calculate one mean, but, I want to do it for each combination of species and environmental variables.

Comment: @MelinaG: please add those to your question